# Organizing apps not in folders

Tags: home-screen, user-interface, accessibility, home-screen-folders

This is a bit hard to explain.. I like having my apps categorized at the home screen (games, Google apps etc.) but I don't like how folders do it. 
Placing apps in folders makes them too small to see which makes me just go to the app drawer and search for them individually. Instead I need something to pop out and let me see all of the apps in the folder without having to click it.

I have tried just placing similar apps together but that doesn't give you such a folder-like effect.

Is there a way to have large folders on your home screen which shows every item or even a way to add small dividers to make some apps look like they are grouped?

I am using lollipop with CyanogenMod 12

Thanks in advance!

Comment: CM12 is based on Lollipop only! :)

Comment: @Firelord Oh, are you sure? Anyway....

Answer (score 0):

First, let me suggest that you specify your device, OS, etc.

Second, it sounds like you would benefit from an [app](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=folder%20organizer&c=apps) (like [Circle Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.dbware.circlelauncher.light) or [Folder Organizer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abcOrganizer.lite)) or a completely different [launcher](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=launcher&c=apps) in order to achieve greater flexibility.

Comment: Sorry about thay. I am using android lollipop with CyanogenMod12